# MS Access - Incorrect relationships

Tags: ms-access, relationships

The relationship between these tables appears to be many sessions with 1 trainer,
 but it should be 1 session has many trainers. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aM0Zq.png)
Have I just misunderstood something? Why does access not use the same notation as an ERD? [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiWyS.png)

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. That Access diagram shows that each one trainer can have many sessions (which seems logical). To have each session have multiple trainers would require TrainerIDs to be a multi-valued field which is a bad practice and not represented in relationship view. We can't answer why Access doesn't use another way to display relations, because we're not Microsoft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> .. it should be 1 session has many trainers.

Then you must have a subtable to hold a record for each trainer assigned a session.

For example, four records with the same SessionId and four TrainerIds.

Same goes for participiants.